# Required an animated product quick view inside grid view in flutter

Tags: flutter, animation

Required a quick view of each product inside grid view. when user clicks on one product the quick view of that product should be opened and others should be closed.
I require the code in flutter with appropriate animation for a good website.

Example view of required gridview

[image]

I have tried to achieve similar results but in my case, AnimatedContainer of same row works properly but not for different  rows.
[My efforts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQ7wJ.png) 
The Structure of my code:
ListView.Builder -> Column -> [GridView Builder, Animated Container]

```
    import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:collection/collection.dart';

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

int totalItems = 5;

double height = 0;
var currentIndex = [0, 0];
var lastIndex = [-1, -1];
Function eq = const ListEquality().equals;
List<double> height_list = List.filled(totalItems, 0);

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    int count = (totalItems ~/ 3) + 1;

    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: count,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return CustomGridView(
            itemIndex: (index == count - 1) ? totalItems % 3 : 3,
            rowIndex: index,
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CustomGridView extends StatefulWidget {
  int itemIndex;
  int rowIndex;
  CustomGridView({Key? key, required this.itemIndex, required this.rowIndex})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<CustomGridView> createState() => _CustomGridViewState();
}

class _CustomGridViewState extends State<CustomGridView> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Column(
      children: [
        GridView.builder(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
            crossAxisSpacing: 5,
            crossAxisCount: size.width < 500 ? 2 : 3,
          ),
          physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          itemCount: widget.itemIndex,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return customContainer(
              index,
            );
          },
        ),
        AnimatedContainer(
          duration: Duration(milliseconds: 120),
          width: size.width,
          height: height_list[currentIndex[0] * 3 + currentIndex[1]],
          color: Colors.blue,
          child: Text(
            "$currentIndex",
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 40),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget customContainer(index) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        setState(() {
          currentIndex = [widget.rowIndex, index];
          //case when first container open
          if (eq(lastIndex, [-1, -1])) {
            print("here1");

            lastIndex = [widget.rowIndex, index];
            height_list[currentIndex[0] * 3 + currentIndex[1]] = 200;
          } else if (eq(currentIndex, lastIndex)) {
            print("here2");

            if (height_list[currentIndex[0] * 3 + currentIndex[1]] == 0) {
              height_list[currentIndex[0] * 3 + currentIndex[1]] = 200;
            } else {
              height_list[currentIndex[0] * 3 + currentIndex[1]] = 0;
              lastIndex = [
                -1,
                -1
              ]; // Reset lastIndex to indicate no container is open
            }
          } else {
            print("here3");
            setState(() {
              height_list[lastIndex[0] * 3 + lastIndex[1]] = 0;
            });

            if (height_list[currentIndex[0] * 3 + currentIndex[1]] == 0) {
              height_list[currentIndex[0] * 3 + currentIndex[1]] = 200;
            } else {
              height_list[currentIndex[0] * 3 + currentIndex[1]] = 0;
              lastIndex = [
                -1,
                -1
              ]; // Reset lastIndex to indicate no container is open
            }
            lastIndex = currentIndex;
          }
        });
        print(currentIndex);
        print(lastIndex);
      },
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.pink,
        child: Text(
          "${index}",
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 40),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: What I think is that It is using 4 item on each row. Based on click index, it is showing expanded widget end of it.

Comment: This is not a free coding service or a free homework service.  What have you done so far?

Comment: My Apologies for not showing my work. I have added my work in my question.